# RPi3 built-in wifi quality v.s. usb wifi dongle

Tags: raspbian, wifi, usb

I have an outdoor application including an RPi3 which requires connecting to an xfinity wifi hotspot but the signal is weak. Therefore I tried adding a USB wifi dongle with antenna to improve connectivity.

I bought two of these: [EDUP Wireless N Adapter 300Mbps 2.4GHz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KV9TQXM)

They are plug and play and I had no problem connecting to xfinitywifi and logging in from the browser. I did however have to disable the onboard wifi interface `sudo ifdown wlan0` as both modules were connecting at the same time.

The problem now is that despite the specs on the USB dongle and the better signal quality, we get roughly 4-5 times **lower** upload/download speeds, compared to the built-in wifi module!

Here are some speed tests, ran on speedtest.net. We tried 2 of these dongles and the results were similar (so it's unlikely the module is faulty)

- USB dongle 1: [run 1](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6856186651.png), [run 2](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6856193329.png)
- USB dongle 2: [run 1](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6856129738.png), [run 2](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6856174945.png)

Here is the `iwconfig` for USB dongle:

```
      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"xfinitywifi"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: AE:34:26:27:68:36
      Bit Rate:144.4 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=96/100  Signal level=55/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Here is the `iwconfig` output for built-in wifi module:

```
      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xfinitywifi"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 0E:51:A4:D3:F1:D2
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:18  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: The onboard WiFi is connected by `sdio` with potentially much higher throughput than external dongles, which share the USB2 hub with other peripherals.

Comment: So the only other solution is the external antenna mod that could potentially violate FCC regulations? That's not neat :/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=139021) is a forum that talks about the range issues. The general sentiment on that forum seems to point that the range on the Raspberry Pi 3 WiFi does not seem to be as good as the USB Wi-Fi Dongle. Other places I have read have said that the Wi-Fi Dongle is not as fast as the onboard Wi-Fi. I guess it could depend on your priorities. Do you want long range or fast?